# Bucket tool based on lower layer in GIMP

Tags: gimp

In GIMP, I want to use the bucket tool to fill in certain areas of my image, but I'd like to do it on an upper layer rather than directly on image.

I think I need to tweak some of the layer settings somewhere to get the bucket tool to recognize the borders of the lower layer, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to have nothing to do with photography, but image editing software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  I needed to check the "Sample Merged" checkbox after I selected the Bucket tool.